# How do I create a reponsive MUI.COM based web app using the full window size (without scrollbars)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

How do I create a MUI.COM based Material UI responsive  web page that uses the full size of the  browser window (without scrollbars)?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8000/dist/index.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app" ></div>
        <script src="http://localhost:8000/dist/index.js" type="module"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
import React from "react";
import {createRoot} from "react-dom/client";

import {Paper, AppBar, Toolbar, Typography} from "@mui/material";

const App = ({}) => {
    return <>
            <AppBar position={"static"}>
               <Toolbar>
                   <Typography>Test</Typography>
               </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>

            <Paper sx={{backgroundColor: "red", height: "100vh", width: "100%"}}>
                <Typography>Test</Typography>
            </Paper>
            </>;
    }

createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<App />);
```

This creates a full width red Paper, but is has a vertical scrollbar.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I am guessing even though you added the `100vh` there's still some padding or margin outside of the div.  You could CSS reset `https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/`  before adding your elements.

Comment: I copied all of the referenced css settings in a new file (reset.css) and imported it into the javascript file. It does not solve the problem.